# Right way to load a local file to snowflake with web interface

Tags: file, user-interface, load

Loading of local files through the snowflake Web interface doesn't work. The error message is "Unable to upload the file to S3". But the loading by SnowSQL works fine. Maybe the ground is that the loading by means of the UI hasn't the step for creating a Snowflake staging area (what is probably set to an S3 staging area by default) ? What is the right way to load a local file into the snowflake by means of UI?

Answer (score 0):

Although it is not recommended to use UI to load files except for quick test/POC, but I am sharing the steps to load with screen shots. You should be able to load by following the steps below

[image: Click load table]

[image: Select the file]

[image: Create the file format]

[image: Click load]

[image: Load result]

Comment: I tried to do that accordingly your step sequence with the database/datawarehouse DEMO_DB/COMPUTE_WH. Of course, I set "Header lines to skip" = 1 by creating the file format. But I still have the message "Staging error. There was an error while trying to stage "emp_demo.csv". Reason: Unable to upload the file to S3." I don't know, why. Best regards, V.Kaiser

Comment: Do you have access to create stage. In Snowflake UI, can you run this and see if it allows you CREATE STAGE DEMO_STAGE;

Comment: Yes, I have access to create and drop stages. The commands create/drop stage worked.

Comment: What is the size of the file

Comment: The file size is very small (< 1 KB)